# ImageButton doesn't work in class

Tags: android, button, imagebutton, classcastexception

I'm a new android developer, I use a `ImageButton` in my application and I added some Image in background. Everything looks good in layer but when I want to use it in some class and use the code below it;s going to force close.

```
Help_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Help_Button);
```

Comment: hv u setted ur layout properly? setContentView()?

Comment: Please post more of the code where you are using the `Button`. Like the method that this code is in and make sure it comes after `setContentView()`. Also adding the logcat would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps show how you verified that `R.id.Help_Button` has the info that you expect to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button` and `ImageButton` are different from each other.  You have to use `ImageButton` instead of `Button`.

Answer (score 4):

Posting your layout xml would help a lot, but my bet is that you're getting a `ClassCastException` trying to cast a `ImageButton` to `Button`. Try this instead.-

```
ImageButton helpButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Help_Button);
```